# isDate control on european data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can i do a isDate() control on a date like 16/01/2008 in vb.net?

Comment: can you please post part of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if 16/01/2008 is a valid date, you do:

```
Dim result As Date
If Date.TryParse("16/01/2008", result) Then
     'The date is valid '
End If
```

Now this will use the current culture set. If you want to validate it against a specific culture, you can do it like this (example with french culture):

```
If Date.TryParse("16/01/2008", Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), _
                 Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
    'The date is valid '
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

If the date format in your input data is fixed to month/day/year and does *not* depend on the current culture, you should use DateTime.TryParseExact:

```
Public Shared Function IsValidInputDate(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Dim dt as DateTime
    Return DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "d/M/yyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
End Function
```